# What's the word called for people who love each other but aren't in a relationship?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

What if two people love each other and they have confessed
And they are more than friends 
But they aren't dating officially... 
Is there any word for that?

Comment: You'll probably get better answers here - https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What does "dating officially" mean? Contrary to the question title, your description of two people who have both confessed love and are more than friends sure sounds like people in a romantic relationship.

Comment: Queen and subject?

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "more than friends": like family? having sex? inseparable? closely linked?

Answer (score 2):

I think  you are referring to:

***[Platonic love](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_love)***:

> a type of love, or close relationship, that is non-romantic.
>
> It is named after Greek philosopher Plato, though the philosopher
> never used the term himself. Platonic love as devised by Plato
> concerns rising through levels of closeness to wisdom and true beauty
> from carnal attraction to individual bodies to attraction to souls,
> and eventually, union with the truth. This is the ancient,
> philosophical interpretation.
>
> Platonic love is contrasted with romantic love

(Wikipedia)

Comment: This word did pop up in my mind, but it is completely erroneous. Platonic, according to MW at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platonic, means a relationship that is strictly non-physical or doesn't involve sex. Platonic doesn't necessarily mean that a relationship ISN'T official. A platonic relationship could be as deep as any other physical relationship, and can ALSO be official, which isn't what we're looking for here.

Answer (score -1):

I'd thought of the word *platonic* but that'd be incorrect, unless you'd added 'non-physical'. What you could be implying is that the persons involved in the relationship could be dating casually.

I'd describe the relationship as coquetry.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coquetry

A common term is **Friends with benefits**